# Opaque tone as hex value from rgba value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, rgb, rgba

I'm looking to create a method that will take an `rgba()` value and convert it to a `#hex` value, however, I don't want the alpha channel included in the `return` statement. It does need to impact the result, though.

As an example:

- If I passed `rgba(17, 160, 173, 1)` I would want `#11a0ad` (#rrggbb) returned, not `#11a0adff` (#rrggbbaa).
- If I passed `rgba(17, 160, 173, 0.55)`I would want `#7ccbd2` (#rrggbb) returned, not `#11a0ad8c` (#rrggbbaa).

```
// Examples
rgbaToHex(17, 160, 173, 1); // returns '#11a0ad'
rgbaToHex(17, 160, 173, 0.55); // returns '#7ccbd2'
```

Essentially I want to eliminate any opacity from my returned `#hex` value, but have the opacity of the original `rgba()` value influence whether or not the returned `#hex` value is the original color or an opaque tone of the original color (derived from said alpha channel).

Here is a visual example that I have pulled from Sketch's GUI:

[image: rgba to hex]

I came close to solving this problem, using the following equation:

```
// rgb(14, 14, 14) --> #0e0e0e
// rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.5)

  const colSpace = 255;

  const r = 14, g = 14, b = 14, a = 0.5;

  const rDiff = colSpace - r, // 241
        gDiff = colSpace - g, // 241
        bDiff = colSpace - b; // 241

  const opaqueR = Math.round(r + rDiff * a), // 135
        opaqueG = Math.round(g + gDiff * a), // 135
        opaqueB = Math.round(b + bDiff * a); // 135


  const opaqueRGB = `rgb(${opaqueR}, ${opaqueG}, ${opaqueB})`

  // rgb(135, 135, 135) --> #878787
```

Sketch's GUI returns `rgb(134, 134, 134)` or `#868686` when you pass `rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.5)`. So my equation isn't too far off.

The equation above takes the difference between the `r`, `g` and `b` color values, and `255`, then multiplies the difference by the alpha channel.

This equation seems to work well when you're working in grayscale and the alpha channel is `50%`. But breaks when you pass a more complex `rgba()` value or a different alpha channel.

Has anyone solved this problem in Javascript before? How can I derive an opaque tone from an `rgba()` value using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need a composition between 2 colors, so use this formula:

```
const opaqueR = Math.round((1-a)*255+a*r)
```

And same for other colors. 255 here is background r commponent, it will work with other bg colors.